# How do I test form submission with Spring MVC test?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy, thymeleaf, spring-test-mvc

Most of my experience with creating controllers with Spring are for REST controllers that consume JSON formatted requests. I've been searching for documentation on how to do testing for form submission, and so far this is how I understand it should go using `MockMvc`:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/submit")
                .param('title', 'test title')
                .param('description', 'test description'))
                .andReturn()
```

However, I'm not sure how to map the form parameters to a model object. I've seen the `@ModelAttribute` annotation pop up in my searches but I can't figure out how it should be used for mapping. In addition, [this quick start guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) from the official documentation does not elaborate on how things like `th:object` and `th:field` translate to HTML and subsequently to URL encoded form.

I have my controller code similar to the following:

```
@PostMapping('/submit')
def submit(@ModelAttribute WriteUp writeUp) {
    //do something with writeUp object
    'result'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered through trial and error that my specific problem might have been Groovy specific. There test code and the controller code, it turns out, have no issues. To reiterate, for testing form submission, use the `param` method through `perform` method of `MockMvcRequestBuilders`. Another thing to note is that this doesn't seem to work if content type is not specified. Here's a sample test code that works for me:

```
MvcResult result = webApp.perform(post("/submit")
        .contentType(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) //from MediaType
        .param('title', 'test title')
        .param('description', 'test description'))
        .andReturn()
```

As you can see, it's not much different from what I posted originally. The controller code is pretty much just the same, with `@ModelAttribute` working just fine.

The problem with my setup though was that **since I was using Groovy, I assumed that getters and setters were automatically generated in my `WriteUp` class**. Here's how the `WriteUp` class looked originally:

```
class WriteUp {
    private String title
    private String description
}
```

I haven't written code in Groovy for a while, and the last time I did, classes like the one above can be assumed to have getters and setters implicitly. However, it turns out that is not the case. *To solve my specific issue, I updated the access modifier in the fields to be `default` (package level)*:

```
class WriteUp {
    String title
    String description
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen the @ModelAttribute annotation pop up in my searches but I
>   can't figure out how it should be used for mapping.

When you mark your `writeUp` object with `@ModelAttribute`, then the Spring container populates the parameters (like `title`, `description`, etc..)  from `HttpServletRequest` object & injects the object to the controller method, when the request comes to the server from the client (could be a Browser or `MockMvc` unit test client or anything else).

Also, few other basic points for your quick understanding:

(1) `Controller` methods are mapped to an URI and `RequestMethod` (like POST/GET/DELETE/PUT et..) like shown below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/submit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute WriteUp writeUp) {

       //Call the service and Save the details

        model.addAttribute("Writeup details added successfully");

        return "writeUpResult"; //Returns to the View (JSP)
     }
```

(2) `@ModelAttribute` will be mapped to an object (like your `writeUp`)  for http POST/PUT requests where the html formd data is part of http body.

(3) `@RequestParam` or `@PathParam` will be used for http GET requests where the parameters are part of URL (i.e., not part of http body).

You can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for understanding the DispatcherServlet request handling & Spring MVC basic web flow.

Comment: I guess my main concern right now is how the HTML form should be like for the ModelAttribute mapping to work correctly. In my sample code, I have title, and description parameters.

Comment: You can refer here for a simple example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/

Comment: The important question is: after all that, how do I test the controller? Which part of the `MockMvcRequestBuilder` can simulate creating of the model attribute that gets bound to the submit handler?